# Need to migrate hosting service without email service downtime

Tags: hosting, nameserver, mx-record

I have a client, who uses Gmail with his own domain for email, he updated his mx records and everyting. now we need to switch hosting providers without any email downtime.
Email service is really important for his work, so this is very very important. 
Would there be any downtime if I just update the ns records?
Domain is registered with Godaddy, current hosting is with Hostexcellence, we will move hosting to arvixe

EDIT: Customer wants to continue using Gmail for business as email. service
According to him, he gets 25.000 emails daily and email service is crucial/very very important!

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Moving your customer's web hosting service has nothing to do with their email service.  As long as the destination of the MX record is not changing, nothing will happen to their email delivery.

Just change the A records for their web site. It is good practice to reduce the TTL on the records as described in other posts or in my original response.

If they are also moving DNS that question has already been asked and answered.  There can be issues if their is a period when neither the new nor old DNS is working.  Otherwise it can be seamless.

ORIGINAL: Keep the old service up until the old `MX` records expire.  Once you have the new service up, GMail could be configured to forward any new mail to the new services.

Prior to changing the MX record, it would be appropriate to shorten the TTL (time to live) on the record to a few minutes.  Old cached entries will retain the old TTL value, so adjust your expiration expectations accordingly.  Change the setting with the short TTL, test, and monitor for email to start arriving at the new address.  Once you are sure the new MX record is working, you can increase the TTL back to what it was.

Once email stops arriving at 'GMail', he can retire that account.

Email may be lost if you specify the new destination incorrectly.  For legitimate email sent to an address which does not respond it is likely only SPAM will be lost.   If you incorrectly specify the address of an unrelated mail server, then it is possible that they will correctly bounce the email.

Consider adding the new server as a second MX record and adjusting priorities.  Use a higher priority (lower preference) initially, then swap priorities once you known the new service is working.  Once email start to flow, remove the old MX record.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, our customer wants to continue using Google mail services. We only need to migrate the web hosting service.

Comment: @emrinho In that case you question seems misleading.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no "downtime". What you'll need to do is think about how you're going to sync all the mail over. This can always be done afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, our customer wants to continue using Google mail services. We only need to migrate the web hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would strongly recommend paying for a 3rd-party DNS provider that's independent of any hosting/email/Internet services; I typically use them for the domain registrar as well because it's a convenient to renew both simultaneously and there's usually a discount for having both.

It will cost more (~$25-50 USD per year, which is really nothing for any legitimate business and I'd walk away from a client like that if that kind of money was going to be an issue), but it affords you the luxury of:

a) having complete control over your DNS zone with *generally* (not always) better support and availability/geo-redundancy;

b) complete independence from any hosting or email providers, so when cut-overs happen, you're in complete control and operating on *your* timeline; and when said provider decides to jack up prices or cancel an offering, your Internet identity/presence/brand (domain) is not held hostage, maliciously or circumstantially.

Back to your scenario: make sure that you can modify your zone **ahead of time** at the new NS (DNS) service provider.  If you cut-over your NS records to a empty zone file, you **will have disruptions** for obvious reasons.

No-IP.com permits you to login/modify the zone *before* a domain transfer and/or a NS change has taken place.  I would suspect that EasyDNS and the like would do similar; I haven't used them, but have colleagues who do who speak highly of them.